# What level monk should I be before I attempt to fight bosses on hardcore?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I'm playing solo and I handled the Butcher just fine, but I remember Belial being much harder when I played non-HC.  Approximately where should my character be at (level/vitality/DPS, whatever's important as a guide) to tackle each of the bosses in Normal difficulty.

I'm playing as a monk if that matters.

Comment: I had to level up from 30 to 32 in order to beat Izual in Normal! Using the build detailed in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66102/what-skills-runes-can-i-use-to-maximize-my-monks-single-aoe-dps).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As always I would recommend being on the overly cautious side with hardcore characters.  I highly recommend being at least level 25 before tackling Belial.  This isn't too hard to achieve if you run the Zoltun Kulle quest for the xp reward and you can get a little extra gold along with it (teleporting to him and killing him shouldn't take longer than a minute).

Finally, builds and gear makes a big difference, but you can 'test him out'<sup>1</sup> in the first stage.  If your health drops anywhere below 50% before he transforms, I'd say its a safe bet the second form is too dangerous to attempt.

For Azmodan you'd want to be in the mid 30s and to be safe, level 40+ for Diablo.

<sup>1</sup> Build yourself a similar softcore character with similar gear to learn the boss's patterns and whether or not your level is good enough to take him.

Comment: I am not sure how HC works, but how can you "test him out"? If you start the battle aren't you locked into a battle to the death?

Comment: @Emerica.: Does unplugging your ethernet cable work?

Comment: @MBraedley Hahahah warcraft disconnects...I am not sure. I would guess not. Thats why I don't play HC, sometimes my latency shoots up to like 1600 and I die. Also wow logging in fomr a different account, thats so sketchy. Figures people would find a way to beat the HC challenge...